# Thinking users interactive system

Tags: asymptotics, queueing-theory, network

I'm trying to solve this exercise but I am not sure about the correctness.

Exercise:
Consider the following measurement data for an interactive system:

- measurement interval: 5 min
- number of users: 50
- number of servers: 10
- average response time per transaction: 20 sec
- Dmax: 1 sec/transaction (the largest service demand at any single center)
- Dtot: 2 sec/transaction (the sum of the service demands at the centers)
- Number of completed transactions: 75

On average, how many useres are thinking?

This is what I tried:

N<sub>not-thinking</sub> = R * X = R * C / T = 5
N<sub>thinking</sub> = N - N<sub>not-thinking</sub> = 45

Where:

- R is the response time
- X is the throughput
- C is the number of completed transaction
- T is the measurement interval
- N<sub>not-thinking</sub> is the number of users that are not thinking
- N is the number of users
- N<sub>thinking</sub> is the number of thinking users

Comment: What are Dmax and Dtot?

Comment: @JamesArathoon thank you, just modified the question

Comment: Aren't server demands usually written "transactions per second"? Is a center equivalent to a server?

Comment: @JamesArathoon in my textbooks is always written in seconds, yes center is equivalent to server

Comment: Now define the variables used in your calculation?

Comment: @JamesArathoon updated

Comment: Don't you have to calculate the minimum and maximum number of users that can give rise to the 75 transactions and then take the average? (assuming a linear distribution between these limits)